# Old web application on server with .NET 4.0 stopped working

Tags: asp.net

I have an old ASP.NET web application on a server, which was developed in Visual Studio 2008 in the year 2008. The server now has .NET 4.0 installed also. When I try to access the web app I get:

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' has already been imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]
```

Is there anything I can do to get it to work without access to the original Visual Studio solution? I believe it has to do with the fact that .NET 4.0 is also installed on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Have you checked the application pool your application is running under? Is it still .net 2.0 integrated/classic, or has it automagically changed to 4.0? If so, try changin back to 2.0.

2) Do you by any chance have a System.Web.Extensions.dll in the bin folder of the application? If so, try renaming it (similar situation as [here](http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/dotnetnuke-support/dotnetnuke-6-running-in-net-4-0-server-error-in-application-version3-5-0-0-version4-0-0-0/))

3) If 1 is not an option and 2 is not the case, do you have any explicit references to the System.Web.Extensions in the app's config file? Are they requesting a different version of the file?

Comment: I had the same issue and change the framework 2.0 works.